# Should form data be sent to the database before or after a redirect to a "thank you" page?

Tags: php

I'm currently using a form that submits to itself using the form action: `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);` and POST as the method. I then use PHP to validate and sanitize the form data.

Now, the next step is to send this data to a database and redirect to a "thank you" page, but not necessarily in that order.

My question is: Is it better to go ahead and submit that data to the database before redirecting or after?

I know I can pass the information on to the "thank you" page and have PHP code at the top of that page that submits to the database instead of doing it before the redirect.

By "better", I mean in terms of security, user experience, performance, and any other important reasons that I may not have thought of.

If there's no real clear winner here, then my second question would be what are the pros and cons of each way?

I feel like this is a good and valid question that I have not been able to find an answer to on this site or any other site. I believe many other new web programmers would benefit from a discussion about this from experienced web programmers. I have found many "similar questions" but none answer this question.

Comment: Process the data, *then* redirect. Why? Because it makes sense. Thank you once you've done all your work and you know it's finished.

Comment: A "Thank you" page is a view. Business logic should never happen in views. The "Model" should have the database relationship defined. The "Controller" should handle invoking actions and saving/delivering data, the "View" should display content relevant to the user's request, and shouldn't perform any logic in order to do so (where applicable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes no much sense to send a user to a *"Congrats, man!"* page if someting went wrong in the back-end, right?

```
UI  >> Submit (Preliminary JS validation Success)
    PHP >> Validate;
         > ERROR?   > Respond with Validation Error (or kill silently)
         > SUCCESS? > Query DB
                    > ERROR?   > Respond with DB Error
                    > SUCCESS? > Respond with header (thanks.html)
```

Unless you're dictated by a business logic (like a payment gateway etc), it's a bit *2002* to send a user to a "Thanks" page, forcing page refresh/redirects etc. You could do this in a more plausible modern way by simply communicating with your PHP using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Send the information to the database, CHECK THAT IT ACTUALLY WENT TO THE DATABASE, and then send the "thank-you."
It is no fun handling user complaints of "What do you mean I'm not getting what I thought I ordered?  I saw the 'thank-you' page."